# how to remove vertically space row in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use two columns
For each one I put a separate row
When I put the form in the second column, the spacing between the column of the previous row is replaced by a new column.
I want to remove the space between the columns

In need to remove space in col-3 and next row col-3. 
I'm use to remove margin and padding but not worked

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <code>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row " >
        <div class="col-3" >

            <form class="form-group form-control">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="نام 
      کاربری را وارد کنید">

                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" 
     placeholder="رمز عبور را وارد کنید">

                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">ورود</button>
                <input class="form-control" type="checkbox"> <label>فراموشی 
    رمز عبور</label>

            </form>
        </div>


        <div class="col-9">
            <form class="form-group">
                <div class="form-control bg-dark">
                    <h3 class="text-center text-danger">ایجاد </h3>
                    <label class="text-white">عنوان</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" size="50">
                    <label class="text-white">تستتتت</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" size="20">
                    <button class="btn btn-success form-control" 
    type="submit">ایجاد</button>
                    <input type="radio"><label class="text-white" class="mr- 
     2">1</label>
                    <input type="radio"><label class="text-white" class="mr- 
      2">2</label>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card card-group">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-header text-center">
                        <h6>لیست</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <label class="text-success text-right">محمد</label>
                        <br>
                        <label class="text-success text-right">محمد</label>
                        <br>
                        <label class="text-success text-right">محمد</label>
                        <br>
                        <label class="text-success text-right">محمد</label>
                        <br>
                        <label class="text-success text-right">محمد</label>
                        <br>


                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
            asdkajsdkajsdkajskd
     </div>
   <code>
```

Comment: Please take the time to share a valid HTML and create a working code snippet here on SO ( <> symbol in the toolbar ) . Include boostrap also. If you do not take the time to create a good question why should we take the time to create good answers.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you need you should have a look at masonry layouts like this: https://masonry.desandro.com/ It's a JS Lib that takes care of the positioning. I don't think this will be possible with bootstrap and css only. Don't want to recommend a tool here - just trying to figure out if this is what you need